# How to use vue js without declared key data on init

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2

I use jquery for communication data with api rest.And use vue js for rendering data to my template, but i have error.

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined"
```

This my code :

```
var dashboard = new Vue({
  el: '#dashboard',
  data:{
    profile: {}
  }
});
axios.get(url_profile, { headers: {"Authorization": "JWT " + token} })
    .then(function(res){
        dashboard.$data.profile = res.data;
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        toastr.err(err);
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: What about your code?

Comment: Please make sure your question includes a [mcve].

Comment: What is the object with `first_name` attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

> If you know you’ll need a property later, but it starts out empty or non-existent, you’ll need to set some initial value. For example:

```
data: {
  newTodoText: '',
  visitCount: 0,
  hideCompletedTodos: false,
  todos: [],
  error: null
}
```

Comment: you can help me with full example, i dont understand.
I add 
el: '#dashboard',
   data:{
    profile: Object,
  newTodoText: '',
  visitCount: 0,
  hideCompletedTodos: false,
  todos: [],
  error: null
   }
still error :(